# Limits at infinity by rationalizing

Tags: limits

I am trying to evaluate this limit for an assignment. 
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \sqrt{x^2-6x +1}-x$$

I have tried to rationalize the function:
$$=\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{(\sqrt{x^2-6x +1}-x)(\sqrt{x^2-6x +1}+x)}{\sqrt{x^2-6x +1}+x}$$

$$=\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{-6x+1}{\sqrt{x^2-6x +1}+x}$$

Then I multiply the function by $$\frac{(\frac{1}{x})}{(\frac{1}{x})}$$

Leading to

$$=\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{-6+(\frac{1}{x})}{\sqrt{(\frac{-6}{x})+(\frac{1}{x^2})}+1}$$

Taking the limit, I see that all x terms tend to zero, leaving -6 as the answer. But -6 is not the answer. Why is that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should have gotten, after the last step:

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{-6+\frac1x}{\sqrt{1-\frac6x +\frac1{x^2}}+1}=\frac{-6}{2}=-3$$

so in fact you only had a minor, though pretty influential, arithmetical mistake.

Comment: I'd say "algebraic" (not arithmetical) mistake.

Comment: @DanielR.Collins In fact, typo-related, as he simply forgot the $\;\frac{x^2}{x^2}=1\;$ summand under the square root sign.

Comment: By direct calculation, when $0<y<1$ we have  $(1-y/(2-y))^2<1-y<(1-y/2)^2,  $ which is useful for problems like this.   When $x>1,$ with $y=6/x-1/x^2,$ we have $x(1-y/(2-y))<\sqrt {x^2-6x+1}<x(1-y/2).$

Comment: @user254665 I don't really understand what your point is, partly because you didn't use /frac to write fractions and that way is hard to follow all that...

Answer (score 4):

it should be $$\lim _{ x\to \infty  } \frac { -6x+1 }{ \sqrt { x^{ 2 }-6x+1 } +x } =\lim _{ x\to \infty  } \frac { x\left( -6+\frac { 1 }{ x }  \right)  }{ x\left( \sqrt { 1-\frac { 6 }{ x } +\frac { 1 }{ { x }^{ 2 } }  } +1 \right)  } =\frac { -6 }{ 2 } =-3$$

Answer (score 4):

Your error is here:
$$\frac{\sqrt{x^2-6x +1}-x}{x}=\sqrt{1-\frac{6}{x}+\frac{1}{x^2}}+1$$

Answer (score 2):

It leads to

$$=\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{-6+(\frac{1}{x})}{\sqrt{1-(\frac{6}{x})+(\frac{1}{x^2})}+1}$$

And so the limit is $-3$